# can't figure out why these two class cant interact?

Tags: python

So I’m trying to to test out how to create two different classes and how to get them to detect each other or the class detects the other you know what I mean, so I tried to create a method called interact and put it in the rock class method multiply, but the problem is that they can’t detect each other I think it’s because I can’t call the rect from a class to another. I tried different methods but they failed or gave me errors. So I was wondering if any of you might have the answers.

Here’s the code:

```
    import pygame
    import random
    import time 
    from pygame.locals import *
    
    vec = pygame.math.Vector2
    pygame.init()
    FPS = 30
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GRAY = (127, 127, 127)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    BLUEGREEN = (0, 255, 170)
    MARRON = (115, 0, 0)
    LIME = (180, 255, 100)
    PINK = (255, 100, 180)
    PURPLE = (240,0,255)
    GRAY = (127,127,127)
    MAGENTA = (255,0,230)
    BROWN = (100,40,0)
    FORESTGREEN = (0,50,0)
    NAVYBLUE = (0,0,100)
    RUST = (210,150,75)
    DANYELLOW = (255,200,0)
    HIGHLIGHTER = (255,255,100)
    SKYBLUE = (0,255,255)
    LIGHTGRAY = (200,200,200)
    DARKGRAY = (50,50,50)
    TAN = (230,220,170)
    COFFEEBROWN =(200,190,140)
    MOONGLOW = (235,245,255)
    
    HEIGHT = 800
    WIDTH = 500
    Font = pygame.font.SysFont('timesnewroman', 30)
    
    gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
          
    # if mouse is hovered on a button it
    # changes to lighter shade 
    # superimposing the text onto our button
    # player stats
    #     player class
    class Player():
        def __init__(self):
            #stats 
            self.right_image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
            self.right_image.fill(RED)
    
            self.left_image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
            self.left_image.fill(RED)
    
            self.up_image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
            self.up_image.fill(RED)
    
            self.down_image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
            self.down_image.fill(RED)
            self.health = 100
            self.hunger = 100
            self.thrist = 100
            self.temperature = 100
            #
            self.x = 50
            self.y = 50
            self.plyrimg = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
            self.rect_plyr = self.plyrimg.get_rect()
            #
            self.width = 40
            self.height = 60
            self.vel = 8
    
        def player_movement(self):
           keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            
           if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                      self.rect_plyr.x += self.vel
      
           if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                      self.rect_plyr.x -= self.vel
      
           if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                      self.rect_plyr.y -= self.vel
      
           if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                      self.rect_plyr.y += self.vel

        def interact(self,rct):
         
         if self.rect_plyr.colliderect(rct):
            print('hey')
         else:
             print('h')
             
        def Draw(self, display):
          gamedisplay.blit(self.plyrimg, self.rect_plyr)
    
       
    #terrain 
    class Rock():
      def __init__(self):
        #stats
        self.health = 400
        #
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50
        self.rckimg = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.rect_rck = self.rckimg.get_rect()
        self.player = Player()
         #
        self.width = 40
        self.height = 60
        self.vel = 5
        self.rect_rck.center = 200 // 2, 200 // 2

      def Draw(self, display):
        gamedisplay.blit(self.rckimg, self.rect_rck)
    
      def Multiply(self):
        self.player.interact(self.rect_rck)

    
    class plant():
      def __init__(self):
        pass

    #mainloop 
    player = Player()
    rock = Rock()
    def Game():
      gamedisplay.fill(GREEN)
      player.player_movement()
      player.Draw(gamedisplay)
      rock.Draw(gamedisplay)
      rock.Multiply()
      
    #Menu  
    class menu():
      def __init__(self):
        pass
      
    #while loop
    while True:
      clock.tick(FPS)
      
      for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
      Game()
     
      pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You've created two different instances of Player().  One in the main scope, the other within the ```Rock``` class.  Please include what you've tried and what errors you encountered.  As such, it isn't clear what you mean by 'interact'.

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), specifically in this case, remember to show your problem using a [mcve]. If you have 30 colors, and the proble is about colors, 2 colors is enough. If the problem has nothing to do with colors, 1 or even no colors is enough. That same goes for class properties and functions: if they don't contribute to the problem you're seeing, strip them out until you're left with the absolute bare minimum example that still has your problem. And _usually_ while doing that, you end up going "oh... right... of course" all on your own =)

Comment: @ewokx you were right, I had the thought that was the problem and then later had the idea to take the self out of player in the rock class but I changed my mind because I thought it wouldn’t work

Comment: You have different options. Either create a method inside Player that gets a Rock instance as parameter and interacts with it (eg: detects a collision) or you can have both classes be instanced inside a top class Game with is the one that does the interactions between instances